# Correct HTML Structure inside PHP IF Condition

Tags: php, html, wordpress

This is my modified Wordpress loop w/ PHP If and Else Condition code.

```
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

<?php
$i = 1;

while (have_posts()) {

    the_post(); 


    if ($i <= 1) {

            echo '<div class="firstp">';

                echo '<a href="'; the_permalink(); echo '"'; echo 'alt="'; the_title(); echo '"'; echo 'title="'; the_title(); echo '">';
                    the_post_thumbnail('article-oneimg', array( 'id'    => "article-oneimg")); 
                echo '</a>';

                echo '<div class="thedate1">';
                    the_date();
                echo '</div>';

                echo '<h1><a href="'; the_permalink(); echo '"'; echo 'alt="'; the_title(); echo '"'; echo 'title="'; the_title(); echo '">';;
                    the_title();
                echo '</a></h1>';

                echo '<p>';
                    the_excerpt();
                echo '</p>';

            echo '</div>';



    } elseif ($i <= 10) {
        echo '<div class="HOLDER-OF-secondp">';     
        include "secondp.php";
        echo '</div>';



    } else {
        // There should be a bunch of HTML mixed in here too
        the_title();
    }
    $i++;
}

?>



<?php else : ?>

<h2>No Posts Found</h2>

<?php endif; ?>
```

**secondp.php** contains this code:

```
<div class="secondp">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('article-twoimg', array( 'id'  => "article-twoimg")); ?>
    </a>
    <div class="thedate2">
        <?php the_date(); ?>
    </div>
    <h1>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </h1>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do here is just to add a holder/container of the secondp.php since it has several posts. But every time I use an `echo '<div class="HOLDER-OF-secondp">';` before & after the `include "second.php";` this happens *(see image below taken using Firebug.)*

[image]

What's wrong with the HTML structure inside the PHP IF condition? I trying to achieve is to put a container that holds all the divs class secondp.

In simple HTML, it's something like this:

```
<div class="holderofsecondp">
<div class="secondp">
a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('article-twoimg', array( 'id'  => "article-twoimg")); ?>
    </a>
    <div class="thedate2">
        <?php the_date(); ?>
    </div>
    <h1>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </h1>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is `HOLDER-OF-secondp` div code in loop ? Can you post the complete code of that file ?

Comment: you have a problem with the condition 
if($i == 1)
{

        echo '<div class="firstp">';


            echo '<p>';
                the_excerpt();
            echo '</p>';

        echo '</div>';
}
} elseif ($i <= 10 && $i >1) {
    echo '<div class="HOLDER-OF-secondp">';     
    include "secondp.php";
    echo '</div>';

Comment: let me know what you want exactly ?? may be your $i is incrementing .

Comment: Hi Ron, i've posted my modified WP loop.

you can also refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22963786/multiple-wordpress-loops

for your reference on the purpose of that loop.

Comment: yea I cot you but let me know waht eaxctly you want ,I will write down the code depending upon that . Do you not need "HOLDER-OF-secondp" this appear multiple time . Just tell me the structure you want

Comment: the end result should be something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/UwZJk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:-

```
<?php global $wp_query;?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

<?php
$i = 1;
$start_hoder = true
$total_posts = $wp_query->found_posts;
while (have_posts())
{

    the_post();

    if ($i <= 1) {

        echo '<div class="firstp">';

            echo '<a href="'; the_permalink(); echo '"'; echo 'alt="'; the_title(); echo '"'; echo 'title="'; the_title(); echo '">';
                the_post_thumbnail('article-oneimg', array( 'id'    => "article-oneimg"));
            echo '</a>';

            echo '<div class="thedate1">';
                the_date();
            echo '</div>';

            echo '<h1><a href="'; the_permalink(); echo '"'; echo 'alt="'; the_title(); echo '"'; echo 'title="'; the_title(); echo '">';;
                the_title();
            echo '</a></h1>';

            echo '<p>';
                the_excerpt();
            echo '</p>';

        echo '</div>';

    } elseif ($i <= 10) {
        if($start_hoder)
        {
            echo '<div class="HOLDER-OF-secondp">';
            $start_hoder = false;
        }
            include "secondp.php";
        if($total_posts == $i && $start_hoder == false)
        {
            echo '</div>';
        }
    } else {
        // There should be a bunch of HTML mixed in here too
        the_title();
    }
    $i++;
}
?>

<?php else : ?>

<h2>No Posts Found</h2>

<?php endif; ?>
```

May be this will help you to get your expected output.

Comment: there's an error on this $total_posts = $wp_query->found_posts;

Comment: you can also try `global $wp_query; $total_posts =  $wp_query->post_count;`.

Comment: see accepted answer for count here:-http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78833/knowing-the-total-number-of-posts-before-to-get-into-the-loop

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you have a loop, an inside your loop you are repeatedly `echo`ing the holder. You want to rearrange your code to not have the holder inside the loop.

Comment: I know, that's really my problem. I don't know how.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="holderofsecondp">
<?php  while (have_posts()) { ?>

    <div class="secondp"></div>
    <div class="secondp"></div>
    <div class="secondp"></div>
    <div class="secondp"></div>
    <div class="secondp"></div>
    <div class="secondp"></div>
    <div class="secondp"></div>

<?php } ?>

</div>
```

`<div class="holderofsecondp">` this will be always out of the loop

or in your code Do this

```
<?php if($i==0) {?> <div class="HOLDER-OF-secondp"><?php } ?>
```

and add the div out of loop but its not good idea . Let me know if you need more help .

Comment: If someone downgrading answers please put your comments bcos its not a competition and we are here to help :)